# Access iOS Certificate in Keychain Programatically using PHP

Tags: php, ios, xcode, macos, keychain

We have a web app that creates iOS apps from a CMS. It builds the Xcode project and we need to be able to archive and export it using PHP. We are able to do this fine from terminal, but using `shell_exec` in PHP it doesn't work.

> Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “XXXXXXXXX”

We think this is because PHP isn't running as the correct user account to have permission to access the certificates in the keychain. We can set the _www user to run as in particular group, but does anybody know which user it should run as?

I understand opening up access to the _www user is a huge security flaw, but it's for an isolated system unconnected to the outside world.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm doing something oddly similar.

Answer (score 0):

And why not copy the certificate in the _www user ?